# What does buying Treek offer?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In the Cartel Market on Fleet you can buy a contract from a little Robot for 1 Million Credits that will lead to a quest that will eventually unlock Treek, a new companion.

What kind of companion is he and does he offer any quests that can be played, like e.g. Vette that has some nice quests? Does hiring him raise my limit for sending companions on Crewskill Missions?

(HK-51 didn't, but HK-51 is essentially free).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Treek can be either a Tank or a Healer.  As a healer she (yes, she!) is at least on par with other healing companions, but she really shines as a tank compared to all other tank comps.  She uses taunts intelligently and has better threat generation in general.</strike>

As of Patch 4.0, Treek offers absolutely nothing compared to other companions.  All companions can now tank, heal, or DPS and are equally proficient at them (apart from minor differences between melee and ranged companions).

She has affection conversations, but no associated quests.  The conversations differ based on your faction.  She does not unlock anything for crew skills, sadly<strike>, but does have a +1 Crit bonus</strike>.

**TL;DR:** She is not worth the money at all.

Comment: Thanks, that makes her pretty useless for me though. Quinn is a good healer and I am a tank myself :P. But good for some alts maybe. Anyway, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Compaired to HK-51 Treek is pretty cheap. Apart from the 1 million credits for the first time. She only costs 300k.

Comment: @Damek And the account-wide Collections unlock isn't bad at 700 CC.